# Sanity check: self-adjoint operator on Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

I just wanted to check if the conclusion below is true, and whether the following reasoning works:

Let $H^i$ be the Sobolev spaces on a compact manifold $M$ and $D$ a self-adjoint (in the $H^0$-inner product) first-order differential operator on $M$. $D$ is initially defined only on $C_c^\infty(M)$ but can be extended to a bounded operator 
$$H^{i+1}\rightarrow H^i$$ for all $i\geq 0$. When viewed this way, $D$ is self-adjoint, in the sense of unbounded operators, in every $H^i$-inner product. That is,

$$\langle Dx,y\rangle_i = \langle x,Dy\rangle_i,$$

for all $x,y\in H^{i+1}\subseteq H^i$. This follows from self-adjointness of $D:H^1\rightarrow H^0$. By the criterion for self-adjointness, we know that $D^2+1:H^2\rightarrow H^0$ is a bounded invertible operator.

**Conclusion:** The bounded operator

$$D^2+1:H^{i+2}\rightarrow H^{i}$$

is invertible for every $i\geq 0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a curiosity, can you suggest me some book reference on these topics?

Comment: There's a nice treatment of self-adjoint operators in Reed and Simon's "Functional Analysis Vol. 1". I learned about differential operators and Sobolev spaces on manifolds first from Roe's "Elliptic Operators, Topology, and Asymptotic Methods" and also Gilkey's "Invariance theory, the heat equation, and the Atiyah-Singer index theorem."

Comment: It's hard to verify the correctness of statements like "by a criterion for self-adjointness" without context. Also, what does "self-adjoint operator $H^{i+1}\rightarrow H^i$" even mean?" The adjoint would go from $H^i to H^{i+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the criticisms, I'll update the question.

Comment: The fact that $D$ is self-adjoint in the $H^0$ norm doesn't generally imply that it's self-adjoint in higher Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Thank you Jack! Sometimes I see the Sobolev inner products being defined as $\langle x,y\rangle_i = \langle x,y\rangle_0 + \langle Dx,Dy\rangle_0 + ... + \langle D^i x,D^i y\rangle_0$, where $D$ is a Dirac operator, and this is what I had in mind here. Given this, do you think the conclusion is true?